# Best Practice to declare POJO in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, collections

While going through Hibernate Mapping examples, I found,

When a class contain Collection, somewhere it is declared as,

```
class Role{
  String roleName;
  Set<Permission> permissionName;
}

class Permission{
  String permissionName;
}
```

OR

```
class Role{
  String roleName;
}

class Permission{
  String permissionName;
}

class RolePermission{
  String roleName;
  String permissionName;
}
```

hbm.xml files differs in both kind of style.

### Database Table common for both

```
Role
-----
role_id(PK) role_name

Permission  
-----------
permission_id(PK) permission_name

Role_Permission
-----------------
role_permission_id   role_id(FK)    permission_id(FK)
```

which the best way one should use and what will be differences considering hibernate in picture on generated queries.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the first in this case. Having a Role with a set of Permissions is the more natural way here. Because that's what your business problem is: You want roles with several permissions for each role. 
If it weren't for a relational database behind the application, you wouldn't even consider going with the second solution, it's a decomposition of the first class structure.

Generally this IS why you use ORMs (Hibernate here) so that you can have a more convenient class structure without having to worry how to decompose it to a relational database. So definitely go with the first one.

(What you'll lose: can't write querys easily for rolePermissions(but it's not a problem as it's just a "helper" class it doesn't model any real world thing))

Answer (score 0):

I would use 1st way, because you will find difficulty with `permissionName` in both classes `Permission` and `RolePermission` as it is redundant in 2nd way :

```
class Role{
  private Integer id;
  private String roleName;
  private Set<Permission> permissionName;
  // getter setters and necessary methods
}

// use one to many relationship from Role to Permission 
class Permission{
  private Integer id;
  private String permissionName;
  // getter setters and necessary methods
}
```

Comment: The DB arch you wrote isn't viable, because you can't have the same permission associated to different roles, you need different permissions with the same name, which is redundant, and you are able to add two same named permission to a role. This makes adding, and deleting roles in the class structure harder.

Comment: I think the DB structure which I gave is fine, I only want to know how it make changes when Hibernate comes in picture for both style of declaring POJO as we need to write hbm.xml file accordingly.

Comment: you have taken permission_id(PK) in Permission table which restrict it contain duplicates, so one permission can be allocated to only one role_id as per Nandkumar Tekale DB Structure

Comment: @JayeshPatel yes, that DB structure is fine, and I think nothing suggests to go with the second way